# Group by a foreign column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a product model which belongs to a category model. I want to get results back grouped by category based on a search query:

```
Games # Category
  Mario Gallaxy # product ...
  Paper Mario
  Mario Bros
DVDs
  Anamaniacs
  Buggs Bunny
```

I need to sort category by name, and then sort products by name. Is this possible? I wrote this, but it's only grouping by name, and returning an array of or objects, which I can't call methods on:

```
# product.rb
  def self.search(query)
    if query.present?
      includes(:category).where("products.name @@ :q", q: query).group_by(&:name)
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

I'm using Rails 4. There is also an ambiguity: `Category.name` and `Product.name`.

Comment: What do you mean “which I can’t call methods on”?

Comment: It says "undefined method name for array class"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
 .order("categories.name, products.name")
```

before the group_by.

group_by acts on an Enumerable and returns a hash, so your query is run when it hits that part of the chain and is no longer an ActiveRecord::Relation.